# How do I manage intranet-wide domain name redirection, similar to a hosts file (Windows Server 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, iis-6

I don't even know the correct vocabulary to use to ask this question, so I'll try to describe it as best I can.

A previous system admin set up our intranet so that you only have to type one word into the browser and it will correctly send you to the correct server.

For example, on Server 1 we have several IIS 6 sites, we'll call them Site1 and Site2. As long as I am logged into the intranet, either by being in the office or using VPN, I can just type 'dev-Site1' or 'dev-Site2' rather than the whole address.

I have now added a third site, but I don't know how to set it up so that typing 'dev-Site3' into the browser will send me to the correct server.

I know how to do this on a local machine by using the hosts file, but I don't know how to do this so everyone on the intranet can also do it.

Environment details:
Windows Server 2003 servers
Windows Vista clients
IIS 6
Active Directory

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's in your DNS server, most likely installed on the domain controller alongside AD. Take a look at the forward lookup zone for the internal domain and you'll probably see the records he created for each site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the DNS zone on your internal DNS server.

You need to add a CNAME alias record.

This record will look something like the following:

```
Name:    myServer.myDomain.loc
Address:  10.3.24.12
Aliases:  dev-Site3.myDomain.loc
Aliases:  dev-Site2.myDomain.loc
Aliases:  dev-Site1.myDomain.loc
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/dns2003/) article will show you how to set up zones and hosts.  IIS can use Host Headers, which is what it sounds like you may have set up.  [This](http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/iis6/) article will tell you more about host headers in IIS.